# Object datasource fetching value from two table?

Tags: asp.net, sql, objectdatasource

I have a listview bind with objectdatasource. i am getting the parameter from URL.

in database. i have two table.
1st table contains unquie for per row. ex

```
pkey  Name   Text
```

1     A      xyz

2     B      zzz

but in 2nd table will be having foreing key with table 1st so the value will

```
pkey   FKey   value
```

1      1       /image/1.jpg

2      1       /image/2.jpg

3      2       /image/z.jpg

4      2       /image/a.jpg

Now for this soultion should i have two listview??
1st listview for 1st table and 2nd for 2nd table???

Please guide me???

Comment: What are you using for your data access layer? Linq to SQL? Plain old ADO.NET in your objects?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using classes that call the database using plain old ADO.NET, you can either make the joins directly in the SQL statement or you can create a view in the database that joins the tables based on the primary key/foreign key values and returns a single result-set, then query the view. If you're using an ORM you can use Linq (assuming the ORM has a Linq provider) to perform the join or map the view and query it separately.

Comment: if i join both the table into dataset then i will be having two rows returning in dataset. suppose i pass '1' for table 1 then it will fetch row from 1st table and joining 2nd table then i will get two row from 2nd table...right???

Answer (score 0):

using linq objects you can perform a join on the tables giving you all the data you are looking for in a single object. And can then put it into one list view.

```
var dat = from x in Context.Table_1
              join y in Context.Table_2 on x.pkey equals y.fkey
              select new 
              {
                   Name = x.Name, 
                   Text = x.Text,
                   Value = y.value
              };
```